can someone assist in writing a powershell script that sets window to static (requires admin rights) but can be ran by a standard user?
I need a powershell script with the credentials  that can set an ethernet adapter to static IP that can be run by a standard user without providing them the admin password is there anyone that can please assist with this ?
I am a novice user but tried some example scripts that seem to work in setting but all still prompt for the password.

Welcome to SO, Eddie. Please take the [tour] to learn how SO works. Especially, [ask]. SO is not a free, bespoke script writing service.

The only way to avoid UAC prompts is to either run in an elevated process to begin with or to disable (parts of) UAC altogether, which is strongly discouraged.
Otherwise, there's only a limited workaround: Assuming that you are an administrator in principle, you can set up a scheduled task with a preconfigured command to be run with elevation, which you can then invoke on demand from a non-elevated session of yours without triggering a UAC prompt.
See the linked duplicate for details.
